# mod_rewrite by accessing the original request URI after forward

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, httprequest

Say for example I have request test.com/.

In DNS this **test.com is pointing to test2.com**. Hence my request is coming to test2.com

I want to do the following.

1. All the request of test.com/* will be redirected to test2.com(by DNS mapping to new server).
2. In test2.com, I have to do the following.

   if(the original request is  http://test.com/*)
           {
               if(user Agent is Mobile)
               {
                   if(!(User Agent is IOS or Android or Blackberry or Windows Phone))
                   {
                       URL rewrite
                   }
               }
           }

3.URL rewrite I want to write a rewrite rule like below.

http://test.com/abc/index.html  ---->http://test2.com/mobil/abc/index.html

I have tried something like below. I am new here.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond expr "%{HTTP_REFERER} -strmatch 'http://test.com'" [AND]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Mobile [AND]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(IOS OR Android OR BlackBerry OR Windows Phone) [NC]
```

Please help me to achieve this.

The syntax may not be correct. Please help me with correct syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Requests to `test.com` will have set HTTP_HOST to `test.com`. You can use this in your rule.

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://test2.com/mobil/#1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you also give me the rewrite rule if possible. I have just written syntax randomly, please also help me with correct syntax.

Comment: This should be what you want. Feel free to ask me if it doesn't work.

Comment: In the mobile also I would like to check for user agent o get the type of phone Iphone/Blackberry/Android/Windows. Can you also include that

Comment: I don't know how the client's identify themselfs. There should be lists on the internet. You just have to replace `^Mobile$` by the proper regex. I thought you were interested in a particular client identifying itself as `Mobile`. I'll add an example for Android.